# Xamarin throwing "System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found" when parsing the xaml page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It was working correctly when I had Xamarin.Forms 2.5 installed, but since I upgraded the Forms nuget package to 3.2 I'm getting this error on my Xaml pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2632

Comment: yeah they claim that they have fixed this issue but it is obviously still there in the latest version @Jason

Comment: do you have XamlCompilation enabled, as suggested in the bug?

Comment: XamlCompilation actually made it work. thanks